# while(gets_s != NULL) is not terminating by enter in C programming

Tags: c

I am trying to write user input to a txt file using a while loop.

But for some reason that I don't know, the while loop doesn't stop by clicking 'enter'.
when I click 'enter', I see "while loop executed" so I know the while loop iterated again even though I wanted to stop the while loop.

How to do it in a right way?

P.S: I use Microsoft Visual Studio recommended by my professor.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
    //writing to file
    char write[100];
    char fileName[100];

    printf("give a name for file: ");
    gets_s(fileName,99);
    strcat(fileName,".txt");

    FILE* pF = fopen(fileName, "w");

    printf("what needs to be written?\n: ");

    while(gets_s(write,99) != NULL)
    {
        printf("whileloop executed\n");
        fprintf(pF,"%s\n", write);
    }

    fclose(pF);
}
```

Comment: `while(gets_s(write,99) != '\0')` is not comparing the return from `gets_s()` to `NULL`.

Comment: You probably mean `while (gets_s(...) != NULL)`.

Comment: Also, `gets_s()` is effectively non-portable and Microsoft-only. Also, Microsoft's implementation of the C Standard's optional Annex K functionality also [does not comply with the C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm).  And it's arguably not any safer than standard, portable C functions.

Comment: actually I tried NULL as well, but it still does the same work...
I changed '\0' to NULL from the post.

Comment: `gets_s` only returns `NULL` when there is nothing to read.

Comment: How are you trying to get `NULL` back? That's only going to happen if you manage to close the input stream somehow. Maybe you meant to check for an empty string (or just a newline) instead?

Comment: yes. that is what I meant

Answer (score 1):

Per [Microsoft's `gets_s()` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/gets-s-getws-s?view=vs-2019), `gets_s()` returns `NULL` on end-of-file and error conditions:

> **Return Value**
>
> Returns buffer if successful. A NULL pointer indicates an error or
>   end-of-file condition. Use `ferror` or `feof` to determine which one
>   has occurred.

Hitting the `enter` key does not close the input stream and cause an end-of-file condition.  It just places a zero-length line terminated with a newline in the input stream.

To do that on Windows from a terminal, one usually has to enter the `CTRL-Z` key combination.

Comment: The documentation refers to a nonexistent sister function `fgets_s`. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some handling there as gets_s() will return and empty string when enter is hit. You can write an extra function to handle that:

```
size_t my_gets(char *buf,size_t len)
{
    size_t ret=0;

    if(gets_s(buf,len))
        ret = strlen(buf);
    return ret;
}
```

Then change your loop to:

```
while(my_gets(write,99))
{
   ...
```

P.S.- You should avoid calling variables with the same name of system functions (i.e. write).